# Stopping a WxPython app's main loop from a thread requires window focus

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a command line utility that starts and stops a WxPython app instance. I'm starting the app in a thread so that I can continue to run commands as well as use the gui app.

My problem is that when I stop the app the console hangs until I focus the app window, then it closes. I'm not sure why the app requires focus to exit.

The app thread looks like this:

```
class RunAppThread(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        self.app = wx.App(redirect=False)
        self.frame = AppWindow(None)
        self.app.MainLoop()

    def stop(self):
        self.app.ExitMainLoop()
```

The relevant CLI actions are:

```
def startapp(self):
    self.app = gui.RunAppThread()
    self.app.start()

def stopapp(self):
    self.app.stop()
    self.app.join()
```

Is there a better/correct way to exit the main loop rather than calling `wx.App.ExitMainLoop()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After calling `wx.App.ExitMainLoop`, use `wx.WakeUpMainThread` to get the main thread to process events.